# How to write a program that returns number of occurrences of a string in another string?

Tags: java, string

So I'm new to programming. I'm using java. Right now I have an assignment I can't solve on a website that teaches java.

This is the assignment

Write a program that returns number of occurrences of a string in another string.

E.g

Input:

First String: the

Second String: The students are working hard in the faculty of Engineering because they love it
Output:

3

Note: You should only use nested loops. Don’t use methods like indexOf or substring.

I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmaoa.png) reached to the code the calculate the number of occurrences but it failed in case of repeated letters

E.g

input:

First String : ooo

Second String : wooooooooooooooooooooow

Output : 21

It's supposed to be 7 since the ooo have only repeated 7 times

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].  

Your question is off-topic because you are asking for us to write your code for you.  StackOverflow is not a discussion, tutorial or code-writing site. The way this works is you are expected to attempt the solution and then ask for help when you run into a problem, explaining clearly what you have tried and what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be simply solved by using [z-function](http://e-maxx-eng.github.io/string/z-function.html) in linear time.

```
int NumberOfcopies(String t, String h){
    // t = the first string i.e "ooo"
    // h = the second string i.e "wooooooooooooooooooooow"

    String s = t + "$" + h; // adding a sentinel character in between
    int n = s.length(); // length of new string
    int[] z = new int[n]; // z array

    // Code ref : http://e-maxx-eng.github.io/string/z-function.html
    int l = 0, r = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if (i <= r)
            z[i] = Math.min(r - i + 1, z[i - 1]);
        while (i + z[i] < n && s.charAt(z[i]) == s.charAt(i + z[i]))
            ++z[i];
        if (i + z[i] - 1 > r){
            l = i;
            r = i + z[i] - 1;
        }
    }

    //checking for all the occurance of string t in string h
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = t.length() + 1; i < n; ){
        if (z[i] == t.length()){
            //A copy is found so skip next t.length chars
            i += t.length();
            ++res; 
        }
        else ++i;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of Occurance : " + res);
    return res;
}
```

> The Z-function for this string is an array of length **n** where
>   the **i-th** element is equal to the greatest number of characters
>   starting from the position **i** that coincide with the first
>   characters of s.

This can be exploited to find the number of occurrences of a string **t** in another string **h**. Suppose we join the string t and h with a sentinel character in between (Sentinel character is a character that does not occur in either of the strings) to form a new string **s**.

Lets us calculate the z function in array `z[]`.

Now lets start searching from the character after the sentinel character i.e. the characters of string h. For i-th character in string h ( such that i-th character belongs to string s) if `z[i]` equals to length of string t (the pattern) then it implies that starting from i-th char, the `t.length()` chars are same as the first `t.length()` chars of string s which is what the string t equals.

example : 
t = *ab 

h = aaabaab*

s = a b $ a a a b a a b 
z = 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 1 2 0 
i = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

for `i = 5` we can see that `z[i] == t.length()`, that means we found a copy. Now to prevent Overlapping solutions, we skip the `t.length()` chars hence now `i = 7`

continuing this will get you the result.